# Avoid to Enter in an input element, Anything except English letters In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can limit user to just type letters in javascript?, In fact when user type anything will be acceptable except numbers,But I mention,for some reason I can't change input type to number?

And in other input type text when user type any things except English letters (characters) , Don't show anything.

```
            <input type="text" name="nationalityCode" 
              placeholder="please just enter number" >

            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="please Enter 
             your name in English" >
```

Comment: did you try input type = "number"

Comment: i don't want use type = "number" , i want use textbox with text type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for changes in the input and remove non-valid characters:

```js
const numberInput = document.getElementById('number-input')

numberInput.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const inputValue = e.target.value;
  e.target.value = inputValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '')
})
```

```html
<input id="number-input" type="text" name="nationalityCode" placeholder="please just enter number" >

<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="please Enter your name in English" >
```

Comment: That isn't really how stack overflow works I'm afraid